# No such remote origin while multiple push

Tags: git

I came across a way to push to multiple repositories at the same time,
[image]

Here is what I am trying to do,

```
$ git remote set-url --add --push origin https://github.com/FahadUddin92/Multiple-Push.git
```

I am getting the below error,

```
fatal: No such remote 'origin'
```

Comment: `git remote add origin http://your_url` ?

Comment: @Protectator: That would just add a single repository to push to. I need multiple repositories.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean isn't it required to first add the remote that way and only then set multiple URLs ?

Comment: @Protectator: Yes you are right. Can you please post that as an answer?

Comment: If someone's coming across this problem, [here](https://github.com/FahadUddin92/git-tips/wiki/Push-to-multiple-repositories-at-once) is a tutorial I wrote to push to multiple repositories at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells that there's currently no remote named `origin`. You're trying to add an url to an existing remote, so you'll need to create it first.

Taking your example, to make it work you'll first need to create the remote using `git remote add` :

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPO-1.git
```

And only then, add the second url to that created remote :

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@gitlab.com:USERNAME/REPO-2.git
```